# Redstone NOR gate with one of two inputs adjacent to output

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a design issue with creating a NOR gate. I have a sticky piston facing upwards and a block immediately to the side and one unit above it with a stone pressure plate on top of it. About 6 or 7 blocks away, I have another iron pressure plate.

I want both the pressure plates to be inputs to a NOR gate whose output is routed to the sticky piston. *If one of the plates is pressed, the sticky piston should retract.*

The problem I'm currently having is that when the stone pressure plate is pushed, the redstone current immediately resulting from that is being routed to the sticky piston, keeping it extended. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if the dust is placed under the block on a line doesn't touch the piston, it won't activate it and let you put around a NOR gate.

A simple solution would look like this :

```
side view :

1:  I    I
2:  BBBBBB
3: P

depth 3, top view :

 |
P|    | (<- both inputs start on this line)
Tv    |
B------

P : piston
T : torch attached to a block
B : block
I : input 
v : repeater facing downwards
| - : redstone dust
```

The problem with this : the piston is still influenced by the first input, by [Update QC activation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity#Update_QC_activation). You should place you input 2 blocks away to remove that influence.

Comment: Yes, but that's to __extend__ the piston. Should I have said NOR gate?

Comment: Absolutely, that tiny detail is crucial, and I missed it, I edited my mistake.

Comment: I feel awful for not communicating this well, I just realized I need to add a bit more information. The solid block with the stone pressure plate is up one unit and to the side one unit of the base of the sticky piston.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How about now ? I really hope it can help you.

Comment: I'm trying this right now. The problem is that the block underneath the first input is keeping the piston extended since the redstone current can touch the piston's extension in the side view.

Comment: You're highly likely a victim of [Quasi connectivity](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity#Update_QC_activation), that's why you shouldn't place inputs near pistons.

Comment: This works well enough. I can just jump to release the stone pressure plate temporarily and when the update occurs the piston retracts for a moment allowing me to pass through if I go quickly enough. Thanks for the link and the diagram.